# Is there any scoop manifest for intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any [scoop](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop) manifest file for intellij idea?

Comment: You can use [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) for automatic updates.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<code>scoop install idea</code>
```

installs idea 2017.1.3
https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop-extras/blob/master/bucket/idea.json

Comment: Works fine - make sure you have the extra bucket enabled

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Ash258/Scoop-JetBrains is registered as:

```
scoop bucket add JetBrains
```

Otherwise you have few packages in `extra`:

```
scoop bucket add extra
scoop search idea

Name          Version              Source Binaries
----          -------              ------ --------
idea-ultimate 2022.1.4-221.6008.13 extras
idea          2022.1.4-221.6008.13 extras
```